# best way to do a for loop with for each loop? - javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is there a good way to do a **for loop** with a **for each loop** in javascript?

I want to make a for loop in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Or ....

```js
Array(9).fill(0).forEach((_,i) => console.log(i));
```

Comment: Its a good code. But could you explain those fill and `_` and all?

Comment: `Array.fill` just fills the array with zeroes so it can be iterated, and the underscore is just "filler" for the uneeded argument, I just used `_` instead of your `e`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(new Array(int + 1).join("0").split("")).forEach((e, i) => {console.log(i);})
```

**int** means iterate times

Comment: Why do you add 2?

Comment: @Barmar i fix that, it should be 1, because when you join you lost 1 item.

Comment: This is almost as bad as `String(Math.pow(10, int)).match(/\d/g).forEach(...)`.